# How to calculate subtotal and total and show the result using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a purshase form with two items.
the first item which is a number box who identify how many adults in the trip.
the second item which is a number box who identify how many seniors in the trip.
for example : 
I want when I select 2 in the first number box, the subtotal next to the number box show me the result of the calculation ( price of one person * 2)
also for seniors section.

I found a code which is work with select and option value :

```
update_amounts();
        $('select').change(update_amounts);

        function update_amounts() {
            var sum = 0.0;
            $('#tickets > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
                var qty = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
                var price = $(this).find('.price').text().replace(/[^\d.]/, '');
                var amount = (qty * price);
                sum += amount;
                $(this).find('.subtotal').text('{{ \App\Helpers\Themes::getSymbolForCurrency() }}' + amount);
            });
            $('#total').val('{{ \App\Helpers\Themes::getSymbolForCurrency() }}' + sum);
        };
```

I have edited this code to my needs like this :

```
$('input').change(update_amounts);

        function update_amounts() {
            var sum = 0.0;
            $('#tickets > tbody  > tr').each(function () {
                var qty1 = $(this).find('#adults').val();
                var qty2 = $(this).find('#senior').val();
                var price = $(this).find('.price').text().replace(/[^\d.]/, '');

                var amount = ((qty1+qty2) * price);

                sum += amount;
                $(this).find('.subtotal').text('{{ \App\Helpers\Themes::getSymbolForCurrency() }}' + amount);
            });
            $('#total').val('{{ \App\Helpers\Themes::getSymbolForCurrency() }}' + sum);

        };
```

But it doesn't work!
this is the Html code :

```html
<input type="number" name="adult_count" id="adults"   min="0" required>

<input type="number" name="senior_count" id="seniors"   min="0" required>
```

this image shows what I need : 
https://i.ibb.co/52qzkh7/stack2.png

Comment: Disregarding the fact that you shouldn't have the same `id` multiple times on a page, the above code should more or less work if you fix the typo: `#senior` => `#seniors` https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/6j9dwsaf/

Comment: doesn't work it shows me $Nan

Comment: The value of an input is a string; you will probably have to turn it into a number first.

Comment: you need to convert your values into a number, you could use parseInt, parseFloat, for qty1, qty2, price, [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: Or `Number()`, or `+$(this).find('#adults').val()`

Comment: @Chris G but in your example you didn't put Number and worked !! and I copied your code and also shows me $Nan